# TCPDF How can I create tables with looped content?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, html-table, tcpdf

I want to create a table for my TCPDF, where the content is inserted from the mySQL database:

```
$html = '<table nobr="true">';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

    $pdo = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id=?");  
    $pdo->execute(array($id)); 
    while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
    $html = '<tr><td>'.$row['name'].'</td></tr>';
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
} 

$html = '</table>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

But I get a lot of error messages:

```
Notice: Undefined index: rows in ...
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in...
Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in...
Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in... 
Notice: Undefined index: rows in...
```

It must have something to do with the table. But I somehow need to create a table, that will not be broken by a new page.

---

UPDATE:

I tested now another solution:

```
$a = '<table nobr="true">';

    $pdo = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id=?");  
    $pdo->execute(array($id)); 
    while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
    $b .= '<tr><td>'.$row['name'].'</td></tr>';

} 

$c = '</table>';
$pdf->writeHTML($a.$b.$c, true, false, true, false, '');
```

But still have the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The op wrote:

> I finally have a working solution:
>
> ```
> $a = '<table nobr="true">';
>
> $pdo = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id=?");  
> $pdo->execute(array($id)); 
> $b = '';
> while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
> $b .= '<tr><td>'.$row['name'].'</td></tr>';
>
> } 
>
> $c = '</table>';
> $pdf->writeHTML($a.$b.$c, true, false, true, false, '');
> ```

Comment: ([Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))